# how to change kde plasma country flags icon?

Tags: kde, icons, plasma-5

How to change KDE plasma country flags icon of keyboard indicator? I replaced my favorite country flag icon in `/usr/share/locale/l10n/ir/` but it didn't make sense. How can i change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the answer. The correct path to replace new icon is `/usr/share/kf5/locale/countries/ir/`.